# Partition Function of a three state particle system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics

I've just finished studying the partition function of a two-state particle system, where particles can have a 0 energy value or E energy value . That is:

[image]

[image]

Where $t_j$ is a variable of value 0 or 1. In this case the set $\{t_j\}$ determines a microscopic state of the system and at the same time determines the energy of the respective microscopic state. Having this form of the partition function i can easily  get a simple expression that will give me thermodynamics properties of the system.

My problem is:

Having a N localized non interacting atoms in which each atom can be in one of three quantum states characterized by the quantum number k=-1,0,1 ,an atom has the same energy E>0 in k=1 or k=-1 state, and an atom in k=0 state has E=0 energy. What is the partition function of this system ?

Comment: Look, just make a minimum effort at answering the question - that's standard homework policy here.

Comment: Ok. I Cant go the same way i did for the two-state particle system. Instead i changed the sum using the numbers of microstates for a fixed energy and finally i use the multinomial theorem to get the partition function :

Z=[2exp(-BE) +1]^N